# Why env does not print PS1 variable?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

When we print the value of `PS1`, it is set:

```
$ echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

We can use `env` command to print environment variables. Why does it not list `PS1` variable ?

```
$ env | grep PS1
# No output here
```

Comment: You should try the command "set | grep PS1".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because PS1 is not (usually, and in your specific case) an environment variable.

There are many variables set in a bash instance which you can list with:

```
$ set
BASH=/bin/bash
BASHOPTS=checkwinsize:cmdhist:…
BASH_ALIASES=()
BASH_ARGC=()
.
.
SHLVL=1
SSH_AGENT_PID=853
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-Ofupc03xWIs7/agent.795
TERM=xterm-256color
```

But many of them are not environment variables. For example:

```
$ echo "$PPID"
1062

$ env | grep PPID
```

You can add variables to the environment by using `export`. So PS1 could be set as an environment variable:

```
$ export PS1
$ env | grep PS1
PS1=\u@\h:\w\$
```

And a variable could be un-exported by removing its export flag with declare (which will retain the value of the variable, just not exported):

```
$ declare +x PS1
$ env | grep PS1
$ echo $PS1
\u@\h:\w\$
```

Or, more drastically, by `unset`ing the variable:

```
$ unset PS1
$ env | grep PS1
```

In bash, `declare` could be used to print the flags of variables:

```
$ declare -p PS1
declare -- PS1="\${debian_chroot:+(\$debian_chroot)}\\u@\\h:\\w\\\$ "

$ export PS1

$ declare -p PS1
declare -x PS1="\${debian_chroot:+(\$debian_chroot)}\\u@\\h:\\w\\\$ "
```

Note the `-x` set for the variable after it is exported.

Comment: On my system I have PS1.set | grep PS1
PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '. Moreover you can add variables to the environment permanently.

Comment: @terencehill What do you mean? That you have PS1 as a variable? yes, this system has it also. As an environment variable? It may be, sometimes.

Comment: I mean that an environmental variable is just a variable that is loaded when the system starts.

Comment: @sorontar It makes absolutely no sense to not export `PS1`. That would mean that if you start a shell from a shell you'll loose your prompt. If `PS1` is not exported this can be considered as a bug.

Comment: @hek2mgl My system does set PS1 in `/etc/profile/` and does **not** export it (I just checked again). The variable does **not** have the export `-x` set when printed with `declare -p` and yet it is carried over to the next instance of bash if I call `bash` in the command line. Try doing `declare +x PS1` and then `bash` to start a new instance of the shell. Does that work  for you?

Comment: Of course not. You know that environment variables get inherited from parent to child process? Just run `PS1=123` <enter> and then `bash` to see.

Comment: I was wrong here. While it is common (imo) that `PS1` get's exported, it doesn't need to because each new interactive shell will source the `.bashrc` again. Srry, my fault.

Comment: @hek2mgl You are confused: execute `declare +x PS1; PS1=123; bash --norc`, you should see the bash version number as the prompt?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Without exporting `PS1` *and* `--norc` the prompt will not being preserved to the new shell. (Of course, how should it). However you won't usually start a shell with `--norc`, that's why I told you are right, `PS1` does not necessarily need to get exported.

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, bash re-reads bashrc, which is avoided by using the `--norc` option to bash. That sets the default PS1 to the bash version number. That PS1 is actually set by the internals of bash (if I recall it correctly, I'll check in a moment), as a null PS1 is almost never useful.

Comment: @sorontar @terrence hill  @hek2mgl thanks for this discussion, this is very informative. Now I recall that PS1 is actually a variable attributed to the shell and not the environment for running other programs, unless ofcourse we `export PS1`.

Comment: @terencehill An environment variable could be set **and** un-set at any point in time, is just a matter of what is needed. In specific, PS1 is usually set in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc`. But there is no need to make it an exported (environment) variable.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on where the variable PS1 is set it can be considered local or environmental (see this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) to set environmental).

If it's local then you cannot print it with **env**. But you can print it with the command   **set**.

Comment: And you can remove a variable from the environment with `declare +x var`.